# Obtaining the curve parallel to the function a/(x^2+b)

Tags: plotting, geometry, parametric-functions

I would like to obtain a curve that is parallel to the function:

```
 y(x) = -a/(x^2 + b)
```

I have tried to calculate the said curve by solving parametric equations, but as I tried to return to the Cartesian coordinates, the `Eliminate` instruction seems not to work (does not converge):

```
   Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, d > 0}, 
 Eliminate[x == t + (2 a d t)/((b + t^2)^2 Sqrt[1 + (4 a^2 t^2)/(b + t^2)^4]) &&
y == -(a/(b + t^2)) - d/Sqrt[1 + (4 a^2 t^2)/(b + t^2)^4], t]],
```

where `d` is the distance between the curves.

Is there an alternative way to obtain a curve that is parallel to the given function in Cartesian coordinates using Mathematica?

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146140/make-an-offset-curve-parallel-curve

Answer (score 11):

- Use `FrenetSerretSystem`.

```
Clear[a, b, r, y];
a = 15;
b = 2;
y[x_] = -a/(x^2 + b);
{{κ}, {e1, e2}} = FrenetSerretSystem[{x, y[x]}, x];
r = 1/5;
ParametricPlot[{{x, y[x]}, {x, y[x]} + r*e2}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

the equation is

```
{x, y[x]} + r*e2
```

[image]

[image]

Or rotation the tengent vector `{1,y'[x]}` to `{-y'[x], 1}` and `Normalize` it as normal vector.

```
Clear[a, b, r, y];
a = 15;
b = 2;
y[x_] = -a/(x^2 + b);
r = 1/5;
ParametricPlot[{{x, y[x]}, {x, y[x]} + 
   r*Normalize@{-y'[x], 1}}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

- Or

```
Clear[a, b, f, reg, dist, r];
a = 15;
b = 2;
f[x_] = -a/(x^2 + b);
reg = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[y == f[x], {{x, -5, 5}, y}];
dist = SignedRegionDistance@reg;
r = 1/5;
Show[Region[reg, BaseStyle -> Red], 
 ContourPlot[dist@{x, y} == r, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -10, 10}]]
```

[image]

- `RegionDilation` seems have bug, and `ParametricRegion` or `Resolve` seems not work.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how I could obtain the equations in Cartesian coordinates of the parallel curve?

Comment: Thank, but that equation in the parametric form. I would like to obtain an equation like x^2+y^2=1 or similar to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=offset+curves.

Comment: @F.Mark I didn't know until now that you needed the implicit function form. It must be a hard task.