# Solve the Differential Equations of r and θ to find the r(θ)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, parametric-functions

There are some differential equations.

$r''+r\theta'^{2}=0$

$r\theta''+2r'\theta'=0$

And $r=r(x)$ and $\theta=\theta(x)$.

And I want to get the $r(\theta)$.

I tried to solve the $r(x)$ and $\theta (x)$ first.

And use $r(x)$ and $\theta (x)$ to get the $r(\theta)$ [like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108770/is-mathematica-capable-of-converting-parametric-equations-into-a-function-if-so).

But *Mathematica* can't solve this differential equations.

```
DSolve[{r''[x] + r [x]*(t'[x])^2 == 0, 
  t''[x]*r[x] + 2 r'[x]*t'[x] == 0, r[0] == r0, t[0] == 0, 
  r'[0] == 0}, {r, t}, x]
```

Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this your classmate?: https://tieba.baidu.com/p/7874713620

Comment: If you're trying to solve Newton's Second Law in plane polar coordinates in the absence of a force, then the first equation should be $r'' \color{red}{-} r\theta'^{2}=0$.

Comment: @xzczd I don't think the same.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If $r'' \color{red}{-} r\theta'^{2}=0$, the problem is typical and the solution is like [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c164h550761p3196900). But unfortunately，I met a problem with $r'' \color{red}{+} r\theta'^{2}=0$

Comment: Fair enough!  It just seemed like a plausible mistake and I figured I'd check whether it was an error or not.

Comment: @xzczd With Mathematica 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022), I receive the error message Part::partw when attempting to execute the code in the question.  Do others have the same experience?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Nasser has asked a separate question for this issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/274571/1871 :)

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Nasser and Michael E2 in [question 274571](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/274571/1063), a bug in `DSolve` prevents it from evaluating the code given in the question above.  However, the bug can be circumvented by replacing `t'[x]` by `z[x]`.

```
s1 = Simplify[
    DSolve[{r''[x] + r[x]*(z[x])^2 == 0, z'[x]*r[x] + 2 r'[x]*z[x] == 0,
        r[0] == r0, r'[0] == 0}, {r[x], z[x]}, x] /. C[2] -> -C[2], 
    C[2] > 0 && r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2] > 0]
(* {{r[x] -> -Sqrt[r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2]], z[x] -> (Sqrt[2] r0 Sqrt[C[2]])/((r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2])}, 
    {r[x] -> -Sqrt[r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2]], z[x] -> -((Sqrt[2] r0 Sqrt[C[2]])/(r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2]))}, 
    {r[x] -> Sqrt[r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2]], z[x] -> (Sqrt[2] r0 Sqrt[C[2]])/(r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2])}, 
    {r[x] -> Sqrt[r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2]], z[x] -> -((Sqrt[2] r0 Sqrt[C[2]])/(r0^2 - 2 x^2 C[2]))}} *)
```

Then, `t[x]` can be obtained as the integral of `z[x]`.  Consider, for instance, the third solution just given.

```
s2 = Integrate[s1[[3, 2, 2]], x] // Simplify
(* ArcTanh[(Sqrt[2] x Sqrt[C[2]])/r0] *)
```

Then solve this expression for `x` and insert it into the expression for `r[x]`.

```
Reduce[t == s2 && C[2] > 0, x, Reals] // Last
Simplify[s1[[3, 1, 2]] /. (% /. Equal -> Rule), r0 > 0]
(* x == (r0 Tanh[t])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[2]]) *)
(* r0 Sqrt[Sech[t]^2] *)
```

So, `r = r0` at `t = 0`, as desired, and decreases to zero as `t` approaches infinity.  For completeness, a plot of `{r[x], t[x]}` for the case just described is

```
Plot[Evaluate[{s1[[3, 1, 2]], s2} /. {r0 -> 2, C[2] -> 2}], {x, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {x, "r,t"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The same plot can be obtained from numerical integration of the ODEs.

```
NDSolveValue[{r''[x] + r[x]*t'[x]^2 == 0, 
    r[x]*t''[x] + 2 r'[x]*t'[x] == 0, t[0] == 0, t'[0] == 1, 
    r'[0] == 0, r[0] == 2}, {r[x], t[x]}, {x, 0, .9999}];
Plot[%, {x, 0, .9999}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, "r,t"}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

Answer (score 2):

- plot the graph.

The parametric curves by `{r[s], θ[s]}` indicate that maybe we need to consider `{θ[s],r[s]}`,that is `θ` respect to `r`.
The second picture is the polar parametric curves.

```
Clear[sol];
sol = NDSolve[{r''[s] + r[s]*θ'[s]^2 == 0, 
   r[s]*θ''[s] + 2 r'[s]*θ'[s] == 0, θ[0] == 
    0, θ'[0] == 1, r'[0] == 0, 
   r[0] == 2}, {r, θ}, {s, -.99, .99}]
ParametricPlot[{r[s], θ[s]} /. sol[[1]], {s, -.99, .99}]
ParametricPlot[
 r[s]*{Cos@θ[s], Sin@θ[s]} /. sol[[1]], {s, -0.99, .99},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

- Simplify the equations.

```
D[r[s]^2*θ'[s], s] == 
 r[s] (r[s]*θ''[s] + 2 r'[s]*θ'[s])
(* True *)
```

It means that

```
D[r[s]^2*θ'[s], s]==0
```

`r[s]^2*θ'[s]` is a constant.

Substitude `θ'[s]=const/r[s]^2` to `r''[s] + r[s]*θ'[s]^2 == 0` we can get a solvable differential equations.

Comment: This solution highly depends on manual analysis. (To be precise, _Mathematica_ contributes almost nothing in eliminating `s`… ) Does there exist a more systematic process to eliminate `s` that can be programmed? That's something I failed to find in past 4 months…